# `resolvconf` changing current DNS. Netplan stict using nameserver

Tags: dns, netplan, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, resolvconf

I need to have my own DNS server in the corporate.
I have the following config set for netplan:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: yes
            addresses:
              - 192.168.1.240/24
            nameservers:
              addresses: [192.168.1.10]
```

At first I have the following on running `resolvectl status` after running `sudo netplan apply`:

```
Link 2 (eno1)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.10
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.10 192.168.254.112 192.168.254.113 192.168.254.114
```

But after a while I get the following:

```
Link 2 (eno1)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.254.112
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.10 192.168.254.112 192.168.254.113 192.168.254.114
```

What's wrong here?
How can I fix using my own DNS using netplan.
And the DNS server is since it is on my local network.

Comment: Your netplan file refers to Network Manager. Is NM running here? If so, revert netplan to its default and make your DNS and static IP address changes in the NM settings.

Comment: Yes NM is there. And yes, changes get applied.

Comment: I shall propose an answer that I hope you will accept: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: It looks like you are being sent DNS server settings over DHCP, which by default are merged with those you specify manually. If you don't want to use these, you can override with `dhcp-options`; see the netplan manpage for details.

Comment: Seems like `use-dns` is not working on NetworkManager backend. @slangasek

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is documented in the `netplan(5)` manpage: "Currently only has an effect on the networkd backend".  So your options here are to either switch to use the networkd backend (any reason not to?), or to manage the interface directly in NetworkManager as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your netplan file refers to Network Manager. I suggest that you revert netplan to its default:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Next, set your static IP address and DNS in the Network Manager settings:

[image]

Reboot.